# SFML Releasing Resources

Tags: c++, sfml

I've recently started using SFML and noticed that there aren't any kinds of "FreeResource" methods provided. For example, `sf::Font` has a function called `LoadFromFile`, but no functions to release the resource.

I thought this was very odd. Am I missing something? Is my only option to create an `sf::Font` pointer and dynamically allocate and delete it?

Comment: I don't know SFML. But consider a `std::vector`; do you ever need to manually free those resources? Nope, it's done in the destructor. I suspect the same for you. Note, having it on the stack is no different, behavior-wise, than `new` and then `delete`. (Except now your code is less safe.) This is called RAII.

Comment: Sometimes we need the same type of resource in the same context, but a different instance of it. If I have an `sf::Texture` that needs to be bigger, I can't simply resize it: I have to `delete` it then `create(...)` a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sf::Font` stores its font data in a `std::map` called myGlyphs (see the [source](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.5/Font_8hpp-source.htm)).  When Font's destructor is called, everything in that map will be freed automatically (by the `std::map` destructor).